# C++ when to use an & in front of an operator overloading function

Tags: c++, syntax, operator-overloading

When do you need to use an `&` before the operator declaration?

Example:

```
class ClassName {
     public:
        // Some constructor here..

        ClassName operator+(...)
        ClassName operator*(...)
        ClassName &operator+=(...) < has an &
        ClassName operator==(...)
        ClassName &operator<<(...) < has an &
     private:
        // Some member variables here..
}
```

When you want to distinguish a postfix and prefix `i++` or `++i` you use an `&`

```
ClassName &operator++()
ClassName operator++(int)
```

But when do you use an `&` for the other operator overload functions? Is there some kind of rule or has it something to do with the memory?

Comment: In short: Assingment operators (e.g. `+=`) which have a side effect on LHS should return a reference to `*this`. The other operators not. post-fix increment is a special case: It has a side-effect but it has to return the value prior change. Hence, you have to make a copy of this and return this copy.

Comment: part of your confusion is probably by the syntax style which should rather be `ClassName& operator+=(...)`, ie the `&` is part of the return type and the usual considerations for whether you return a refernce or value do apply (taking into account conventions for operator overloads)

Comment: This is why I hate separating `&` and `*` from type and sticking it to the other token. It's utterly confusing for the readers and can be easily overlooked as well.

Comment: So you recommend sticking the `&` to the `ClassName`?

Comment: definitely yes. It is a matter of style, but the only correct style is `ClassName&` for the return type ;). Note that this clashes with variable declarations where `int* i,j;` declares a pointer and an `int`, tough if you declare one variable per line, all is fine

Comment: @Michiel https://kera.name/articles/2010/05/tomalaks-monday-monstrous-rant-i-align-your-asterisks/

Comment: @Michiel Just be aware that a lot of [silly] people disagree with this ;)

Comment: @formerlyknownas_463035818 Well I just copied the examples in my post from my textbook from university.. quit unfortunate that they use the wrong style..

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit thanks man, I'll give it a read a.s.a.p :)

Comment: technically speaking it is not "wrong", just ugly and confusing, which I actually would call "wrong" :P

Comment: @formerlyknownas_463035818 it's just wrong.. haha ;)

Comment: i just dont want to mix facts with opinions, even if I have a strong opinion, thats all

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**tl;dr: Same as with any function. Do you return by value, or by reference?**

---

It might be clearer if you align your ampersand to the left (which has no semantic effect, just like with `char* str` vs `char *str`):

```
ClassName& operator++()
ClassName operator++(int)
```

So the choice depends on whether you want to return a reference to the existing object:

```
ClassName& operator++()
{
    this->someMember += 1;
    return *this;
}
```

…or a nice new one:

```
ClassName operator++(int)
{
    // Post-fix operator so we have to return the "old" unmodified version
    ClassName old = *this;
    this->someMember += 1;
    return old;
}
```

In the first case, returning by value would be confusing to the user of your `++`, because:

- there was an unnecessary copy, and
- further operations on the result of `++` would not affect the original object.

In the second case, returning by reference would be *bad* because:

- it would be a dangling reference to a local variable.

Comment: Oh so (1) `ClassName &operator+=(...)` and (2) `ClassName operator+=(...)` both work, but (1) returns an existing object, while (2) returns a new one?

Comment: @Michiel Basically. Same as with any function. Do you return by value, or by reference? That's your choice (though with operators there are strong conventions, for good reasons)

Comment: `or a nice new one:` I'm not going to lie - I thought new wasn't used for modern c++.

I'll go home now

Comment: @UKMonkey You're immediately fired

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit given the speed of the reply - I can't fault the 'immediately' part

Answer (score 6):

> When do you need to use an & before the operator declaration?

The & symbol declares the return type of the function to be a reference. More specifically, an lvalue reference. So, you use & when you want to return an lvalue reference, and don't use & when you want to return a non-reference.

So, when do you want to return a reference from an operator overload? A concise rule of thumb is that you should return a reference if the built-in operator for non class types is an lvalue expression, and return a non-reference when the built-in operator is an rvalue expression. There are exceptions to this. For example, sometimes you cannot return a reference. Perhaps you need to return some sort of wrapper object that behaves like a reference; such wrappers are typically returned by value.

Assignment operators, including the compound assignment operators such as `+=` conventionally return a reference to `*this`.

Postfix operator conventionally returns the previous value. As such, it cannot return a reference to `*this`, which contains the current value. Prefix operator does return the current value, so it can return a reference. The prefix increment of a non-class object is an lvalue expression, so returning an lvalue (i.e. a reference) from the operator overload is a good convention.